# Getting intent result from ondestroy

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I can get the result from intent using `onBackpressed` :

```
returnIntent.putExtra("isBack", true);
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
finish();
```

And this is my `onActivityResult` :

```
if (requestCode == 1) 
        {
             if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){      
                 boolean isBack = data.getBooleanExtra("isBack", false);
                 if(isBack == true)
                     searchEditText.setText("");
             }
         }
```

However, now i need to do the `setResult` **not** in the `onBackpressed`, so i was thinking of `onDestroy`.

I tried to move the `setResult` to `onDestroy` but the `onActivityResult` cant get my result.

I also have tried `onStop` and `onPause`, but none of them are working.

Please help me, Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Override in finish()

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra("isBack", true);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data); 

    super.finish();
}
```

Comment: Yes, i just realize i can override the finish(). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to do?

You could call `setResult()` as soon as the action finished, no need to wait until activity finish/destroy.

Answer (score 1):

It is not mandatory to put setResult() just before exiting the activity. You can put it anywhere before after your required action is accomplished in the activity. It will be called properly after your activity exit.

Normally when one activity is called from another (or parent activity comes up when child is finished), the destruction process of one activity and construction process of another activity happen in parallel. It is not like first the activity is completely destroyed and then another activity is created. So the process happen in parallel and asynchronously. So you should not do it in onStop(), onDestory() and similar methods.